# Как получить данные из CoroutineScope и вставить во View

Tags: android, kotlin, view, dagger2, coroutine

Получаю следующее исключение при попытке получить данные через корутины из базы Room
Как можно решить данное исключение?

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: tv_pf_email must not be null`

Код

```kotlin
fun mapProfileData() {
        val profile = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.email?.let {
            profileViewModel.getProfileByEmail(it)
        }

        tv_pf_email.text = profile?.email.toString()
        tv_pf_name.text = profile?.name.toString()
        tv_pf_city.text = profile?.city.toString()
        tv_pf_phone_number.text = profile?.phoneNumber.toString()
    }


fun getProfileByEmail(email: String): User? {
        viewModelJob = viewModelScope.launch {
            val resp = interactor.getUserByEmail(email)
            _user.postValue(resp)
        }

        return _user.value
    }

override suspend fun getUserByEmail(email: String): User {
        return repository.getUserByEmail(email)
    }

override suspend fun getUserByEmail(email: String): User = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val user = profileDao.getUserByEmail(email)
        user
    }

class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AppInjector.plusProfileComponent().inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        activity?.title = "Профиль"
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment, container, false)
        signOut(view)
        mapProfileData(view)
        return view
    }

    fun mapProfileData(view: View) {
        val profile = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.email?.let {
            profileViewModel.getProfileByEmail(it)
        }

         view.tv_pf_email.text = profile?.email.toString()
         view.tv_pf_name.text = profile?.name.toString()
         view.tv_pf_city.text = profile?.city.toString()
         view.tv_pf_phone_number.text = profile?.phoneNumber.toString()
    }
```

Comment: У вас все банально похоже на проблему с view binding, ни Room, ни корутины тут ни при чем.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Добавил полный код. Теперь я передаю view (спасибо за эту подсказку), но в итоге на экране вижу null

Comment: Причин почему null может быть много. Расставьте брейкпоинты и посмотрите откуда он берется.